# GridView.getItemAtPosition is always null (but list displays items)

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a GridView object. It is showing photos from the users library. This is working and the list is scrollable on screen.

However whenever I try to get the item that was clicked, I get null.

```
_gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
_gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    System.out.println("Getting pos " + position + " and obj is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                }
            });
```

The position it prints out is always correct. If I tap the first item it tells me position is 0. However, it says the item is null (which makes no sense to me as its displaying just fine on the phone).

Can you advise me on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main reason is usually because your version of `getItem` is returning null. `getItem` is supposed to return the item a position in your dataset, and `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(...)` calls internally `adapter.getItem(position)`.

and please get rid of this cast: `ImageView image = (ImageView) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));`